# Multiple parameters to SQL JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, parameter-passing, jdbctemplate

I have query like

```
`Select * from Table1 where xyz in (List of String to be Supplied).
```

In my java code. I have a dao object in which I am calling this sql using jdbc template.
The method takes in a list of String and that needs to be supplied to this SQl. I have my row-mapper.

How to write the SQl and how to pass the list of variables?

My SQL will run on a Teradata Db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) which, as the doc says:

> It also allows for expanding a List of values to the appropriate number of placeholders.

So you just need

```
String sql = "select * from Table1 where xyz in :list"; 
// or String sql = "select * from Table1 where xyz in (:list)";
// I can't remember which one is right
Map parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("list", theListOfXyz);
List<Foo> result = template.query(sql, parameters, rowMapper);
```